# bash - using sed to delete the nth item from a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I don't need a column in a table anymore and need to change the script for inserting data. For example, I don't need the 'code' column anymore. How do I remove the third item for each value?

```
-- Create table variable
CREATE TABLE currency (
  country  VARCHAR(100),
  currency VARCHAR(100),
  code     VARCHAR(100),
  symbol   VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Insert currency records
INSERT INTO currency (country, currency, code, symbol)
VALUES
('Albania', 'Leke', 'ALL', 'Lek'),
('Afghanistan', 'Afghanis', 'AFN', '؋');
```

Comment: It looks like one-time import. You can just leave it there and then `DROP COLUMN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` with regex to achieve this. The following will remove (in-place) the 3rd column from all rows that start after `VALUES` row:

```
sed -i "s/\(('[a-zA-Z]\+', '[a-zA-Z]\+',\) '[a-zA-Z]\+',\( '.*').*\)/\1\2/g" input.sql
```

The above will not remove `code VARCHAR(100),` from the `CREATE TABLE` statement or `code` from the `INSERT INTO` line. If you want to remove these as well, you can use the following code:

```
cat input.sql | sed '/code\s\+VARCHAR/d' | sed 's/\(INSERT INTO .*\)code, \(.*\)/\1\2/' | sed "s/\(('[a-zA-Z]\+', '[a-zA-Z]\+',\) '[a-zA-Z]\+',\( '.*').*\)/\1\2/g"
```

This will output:

```
-- Create table variable
CREATE TABLE currency (
  country  VARCHAR(100),
  currency VARCHAR(100),
  symbol   VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Insert currency records
INSERT INTO currency (country, currency, symbol)
VALUES
('Albania', 'Leke', 'Lek'),
('Afghanistan', 'Afghanis', '؋');
```